# How to compare values inside template if

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

How to check values inside template if in lwc?
Something like:
JS file:
val1 =2;
val2=2;
<template if:true ({val1}=={val2})>

is it possible? if yes then pls provide the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is minimal expression language in the template itself, so you have to evaluate the expression in the JavaScript:

```
export default class MyLwc extends LightningElement {

    val1 = 2;
    val2 = 2;

    // Use a more meaningful name here where possible
    get valuesEqual() {
        return val1 === val2;
    }
```

and can then reference the result:

```
<template if:true={valuesEqual}>
```

From the [HTML Template Directive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_directives) documentation:

> The expression can be a JavaScript identifier (for example, person) or
> dot notation that accesses a property from an object
> (person.firstName). The engine doesn’t allow computed expressions
> (person[2].name['John']). To compute the value of expression, use a
> getter in the JavaScript class.

So note this idiom is possible (where `items` is an array):

```
<template if:false={items.length}>
    No items
</template>
```